# Why does svn commit not change the version number of unaffected files?

Tags: svn

Suppose I have two files in my repo, `A.txt` and `B.txt`, and they are both currently at revision X.  If I modify `A.txt` and then `svn commit`, then file `A.txt` will be at revision X+1 in my working copy, while `B.txt` will still be at revision X.

Since a revision number is supposed to be a snapshot of the directory tree, it seems to me that `B.txt` should also be at revision X+1. Indeed, if I were to then do `svn update`, then the revision number for `B.txt` in my working copy will be X+1.  So what is the reason for allowing mixed revision numbers in a working copy in `svn` if we know that whenever there are mixed revisions, there are no differences between revisions X and X+1 in files that are not changed?

Answer (score 0):

As I was about to submit this question, I thought of the answer.  Suppose I have revision X checked out and I make changes to `A.txt`.  Suppose in the mean time, another user makes changes and commits them to the repo as revision X+1.  If the other user changed `A.txt`, then I will not be able to commit without updating my working version; however, if the other user changed `B.txt` but left `A.txt` alone without changing it, then I *am* able to commit my changes without updating.

When I `svn commit`, my file `A.txt` will be at revision X+2, but `B.txt` in my working version is still at revision X because I never updated it to receive the other user's changes.